# Terraform user_data ng build

Tags: angular, terraform, ng-init

I've got a terraform script to stand up an EC2 instance which installs git, nvm, node, and clones an angular2 repo from github.

````
# install angular cli globally
npm install -g @angular/cli &> globalCli.log
cd test
# install node_modules
npm install &> npmInstall.log
# create dist folder
ng build --output-path 'dist' >& ngBuild.log
ng update >& ngUpdate.log
#start the app
(npm start) &> npmStart.log```
````

For some reason the terrform script returns this error to ngBuild.log

```
Path must be a string. Received undefined
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
at Object.join (path.js:1211:7)
at Function.fromProject (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:53:39)
at Object.<anonymous> (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:11:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Class.includedCommands (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/addon/index.js:23:16)
at /test/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:326:61
at Array.forEach (native)
at Project.addonCommands (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:325:15)
at Project.eachAddonCommand (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:360:30)
at module.exports (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:33:13)
at CLI.<anonymous> (/test/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:42:26)
at tryCatch (/fsi-ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
at invokeCallback (/test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
at publish (/test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
at flush (/test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Oddly enough if I ssh into the ec2 instance, and run the same `ng build` command, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue (I searched to try and find an answer and couldn't find one that solved my problem).

Ultimately, it boiled down to an @angular/cli versioning issue. When I was manually running `ng build` inside the ec2 instance I was able to see that there was a difference between the global cli and the local cli. I updated `package.json` to use `latest` and then had to add the following to my `angular-cli.json` file `"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts"`.

The log I was outputting still says path requires a string however I believe thats just a scripting issue that's arising through terraform. `/dist/` installs successfully!